# "Keep only last email from sender" functionality

Tags: plugins, gmail, imap

I saw this functionality in a Microsoft Web Outlook demo.

**Keep only last email from sender**.

I would like to have this for my gmail accounts.
How could this be accomplished?

- Filters ?
- Existing Plugin ?
- Lab functionality ?

Or would one have to write there own via imap or some google api?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this myself. But something that I came across when doing a similar search. So, posting this here for you and other's help who're looking for something similar. I have to try this too.

http://www.johneday.com/422/time-based-gmail-filters-with-google-apps-script#comment-179

---

### Update: Since the link above is broken, pasted the content from web archive.

Create time-based Gmail filters with Google Apps Script
Somewhere between spam and archived messages are the emails that I want to glance at briefly, yet I don’t want clogging my Inbox when I forget to delete them. Apple Mail lets you create a rule for messages received greater than x days old. However, because the condition is only tested as messages arrive, none of the messages will meet the criteria. You can get around this by reapplying the rule, but that defeats the purpose of automating the process. Thankfully, Gmail users can take advantage of Google Apps Script to create time-based events that will move, mark, or label your messages without having to open a mail client.

For this example, let’s create a script that will delete all messages from the “delete me” label that are older than two days. First, make a new Gmail filter and populate the search options so it will catch all of your semi-spam. Remember to create and apply the “delete me” label to the matched messages.

Go to https://script.google.com , create a script for a Blank Project, and paste the code below into the editor. You may edit the delayDays variable to specify how many days should pass before the matched messages will be moved to the trash.

```
function cleanUp() {
  var delayDays = 2 // Enter # of days before messages are moved to trash
  var maxDate = new Date();
  maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate()-delayDays);
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("delete me");
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    if (threads[i].getLastMessageDate()<maxDate)
      {
        threads[i].moveToTrash();
      }
  }
}
```

After you save your script, run it by either clicking the play button or by selecting it from the Run menu at the top of the screen. Authorize the script to access your Gmail account, then schedule the interval in which you would like the script to run. Select Current script’s triggers… from the Resources menu and select a period, I chose every 30 minutes.

Notice that your Trash is now filled with old messages, previously destined to collect dust in your Inbox. To save one of your “delete me” messages, simply remove the label.

Time-based filters can also be used to auto-archive emails older than x days. You can simplify your javascript function by using the search method to combine several advanced search operators. For example, using the script below I can archive every thread in my Inbox that is read, older than two days, and not labeled “delete me”.

```
function archiveInbox() {
    // Every thread in your Inbox that is read, older than two days, and not labeled "delete me".
    var threads = GmailApp.search('label:inbox is:read older_than:2d -label:"delete me"');
      for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        threads[i].moveToArchive();
    }
}
```

Deleting or archiving thousands of messages may take some time. You can speed things up and minimize “Exceeded maximum execution time” errors by processing threads in batches of 100. Here are several examples:

Batch Delete Functions

```
function batchDeleteA() {
  var batchSize = 100 // Process up to 100 threads at once
  var threads = GmailApp.search('label:"delete me" older_than:2d');
  for (j = 0; j < threads.length; j+=batchSize) {
    GmailApp.moveThreadsToTrash(threads.slice(j, j+batchSize));
  }
}

function batchDeleteB() {
  var mySearch = "'label:\"delete me\" older_than:2d'"
  var batchSize = 100 // Process up to 100 threads at once
  while (GmailApp.search(mySearch, 0, 1).length == 1)
  {
    GmailApp.moveThreadsToTrash(GmailApp.search(mySearch, 0, batchSize));
  }  
}

function batchDeletePromotions() {
  // include one or more categories below
  // valid categories include ["primary", "promotions", "social", "updates", "forums"];  
  // category descriptions: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/3094596?hl=en
  var categories = ["social", "promotions", "forums"];
  
  var batchSize = 100 // Process up to 100 threads at once
  for (i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    var threads = GmailApp.search('label:inbox category:'+categories[i]+' older_than:2d');
    for (j = 0; j < threads.length; j+=batchSize) {
      GmailApp.moveThreadsToTrash(threads.slice(j, j+batchSize));
    }
  }
}

function multipleLabels() {
  var myLabels = {'"delete me"': "2d", '"scripts"': "5d"};
  var batchSize = 100; // Process up to 100 threads at once
  for(aLabel in myLabels)
  {
    var threads = GmailApp.search('label:'+aLabel+' older_than:'+myLabels[aLabel]+'');
    for (j = 0; j < threads.length; j+=batchSize) {
      GmailApp.moveThreadsToTrash(threads.slice(j, j+batchSize));
    }
  }  
}
```

Batch Archive Functions

```
function batchArchiveA() {
  var batchSize = 100 // Process up to 100 threads at once
  var threads = GmailApp.search('label:inbox is:read older_than:1d -label:"delete me"');
  for (j = 0; j < threads.length; j+=batchSize) {
    GmailApp.moveThreadsToArchive(threads.slice(j, j+batchSize));
  }
}

function batchArchiveB() {
  var mySearch = "'label:inbox is:read older_than:2d -label:\"delete me\"'"
  var batchSize = 100 // Process up to 100 threads at once
  while (GmailApp.search(mySearch, 0, 1).length == 1)
  {
    GmailApp.moveThreadsToArchive(GmailApp.search(mySearch, 0, batchSize));
  }  
}
```

Other Functions

```
function markMutedThreadsRead() {
  // mark muted threads as read and remove label
  var labelName= "my label",
      batchSize = 100,
      threadLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(labelName),
      threads = GmailApp.search('is:muted');
  
  for (j = 0; j < threads.length; j+=batchSize) {
      GmailApp.markThreadsRead(threads.slice(j, j+batchSize));
      if (threadLabel) {
        threadLabel.removeFromThreads(threads.slice(j, j+batchSize));
      }
  } 
}
```

Comment: The blog is offline, fails with Access Denied. Found it in the Internet Archive, though: https://web.archive.org/web/20180911180312/http://www.johneday.com:80/422/time-based-gmail-filters-with-google-apps-script and tried, it works!

Comment: Thanks @keremispirli, I update the answer with the contents from your link. Thanks!!